# Handshake error with the openssl command s_client

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am testing a https server with the openssl command:

`openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxx.com:8773`

I got the some handshake error message as below.

```
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    
    depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA verify return:1 
    
    depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA verify return:1 
    
    depth=0 C = CN, ST = \E6\B5\99\E6\B1\9F\E7\9C\81, L = \E6\9D\AD\E5\B7\9E\E5\B8\82, O = \E6\9D\AD\E5\B7\9E\E6\81\92\E7\94\9F\E8\8A\B8\E6\B3\B0\E7\BD\91\E7\BB\9C\E7\A7\91\E6\8A\80\E6\9C\89\E9\99\90\E5\85\AC\E5\8F\B8, OU = \E6\81\92\E7\94\9F\E8\8A\B8\E6\B3\B0\E7\A0\94\E5\8F\91\E9\83\A8, CN = *.xxx.com verify return:1
    
    140098959959704:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1487:SSL alert number 40
    140098959959704:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
```

Is it a real error and does it mean that the handshake is failed? What may cause that and how to debug it?

Add detailed debug info:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x92fa60 [0x92fae0] (265 bytes => 265 (0x109))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 04 01 00 01-00 03 03 db 16 2a 5c d8   .............*\.
0010 - 26 d0 d3 89 36 b2 b0 11-3d 46 3a 1f c2 86 4c e2   &...6...=F:...L.
0020 - 32 e8 ad 2f 99 03 69 72-60 07 2e 00 00 82 c0 30   2../..ir`......0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b   .,.(.$.........k
0040 - 00 6a 00 39 00 38 00 88-00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .j.9.8.....2...*
0050 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0060 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67   .+.'.#.........g
0070 - 00 40 00 33 00 32 00 9a-00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 31   .@.3.2.....E.D.1
0080 - c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e-c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f   .-.).%.......<./
0090 - 00 96 00 41 c0 11 c0 07-c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04   ...A............
00a0 - c0 12 c0 08 00 16 00 13-c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 ff   ................
00b0 - 01 00 00 55 00 0b 00 04-03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 1c   ...U............
00c0 - 00 1a 00 17 00 19 00 1c-00 1b 00 18 00 1a 00 16   ................
00d0 - 00 0e 00 0d 00 0b 00 0c-00 09 00 0a 00 23 00 00   .............#..
00e0 - 00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01-06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02   ... ............
00f0 - 05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03-03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01   ................
0100 - 02 02 02 03 00 0f 00 01-01                        .........
read from 0x92fa60 [0x935040] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 42 02                                 ....B.
0007 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x92fa60 [0x93504a] (64 bytes => 64 (0x40))
0000 - 00 3e 03 03 d3 e8 11 03-4a 8a 9d 93 85 f2 e4 aa   .>......J.......
0010 - 9f 03 d0 b2 eb f3 ef 7e-bd 41 6b 2c 36 70 55 06   .......~.Ak,6pU.
0020 - b8 0d bb 03 00 c0 2f 00-00 16 ff 01 00 01 00 00   ....../.........
0030 - 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00-23 00 00 00 0f 00 01 01   ........#.......
read from 0x92fa60 [0x935043] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 03 0f 3c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a real error and does it mean that the handshake is failed?

Yes.

> What may cause that and how to debug it?

Since the server has already sent its certificate the key exchange is probably not the problem. One of the reasons the handshake could fail at this stage is that the server is requesting a client certificate but the client does not send one.

```
read from 0x92fa60 [0x935043] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 54                                    ....T
read from 0x92fa60 [0x935048] (84 bytes => 84 (0x54))
0000 - 0d 00 00 4c 03 01 02 40-00 1e 06 01 06 02 06 03   ...L...@........
0010 - 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01-04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02   ................
0020 - 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03-00 26 00 24 30 22 31 20   .........&.$0"1 
0030 - 30 1e 06 03 55 04 03 0c-17 59 75 6e 74 61 69 20   0...U....Yuntai 
0040 - 4e 65 74 77 6f 72 6b 20-58 69 65 68 65 20 43 41   Network Xiehe CA
0050 - 0e
```

I guess that this part means that the server is expected a client certificate, issued by Yuntai Network Xiehe CA. Your client is clearly not providing one, that's why the handshake fails.

Comment: HI, thanks so much for your help, and I attached the debug info which is appended to my question.

Comment: @user3236879: this is not a discussion forum but a strict Q&A site. Please provide the information by updating the question, not by adding "answers" - since the latter ones are clearly intended for real answers.